# Added drive to PERC6/i raid5 array instead of replacing - is there a way to fix this?

Tags: linux, raid, dell-perc, megacli

This is a 3 drive RAID5.  The disk in slot 1 failed.  After the disk was replaced, I ran:

MegaCli64 -LDRecon -Start -r5 -Add -PhysDrv[32:1] -L0 -a0

Obviously that was not the correct command as now I have a degraded 4 disk raid5 instead of a good 3 disk raid5.

Is there any way to correct this?

Some more info:

```
Primary RAID Level             : 5
RAID Level Qualifier           : 3
Secondary RAID Level           : 0
Strip Size per DDF            : 7 (64K)
# of drivers per span          : 4
# of spans                     : 1
Init Progress State            : No init in progress
State                          : DEGRADED
Consistentcy                   : Not Consistent or Not Applicable
Span# 0                        :
Start Block     : 0MB
 # blocks        : 139392MB
 Array Index     : 0

Total size of the logical drive: 418176MB
Logical Drive owner's Device ID: 255
Number of Physical Devices  : 4
Device IDs:     0
Device IDs:     0
Device IDs:     2
Device IDs:     1
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're using MegaCli instead of Dell OpenManage Server Administrator? MegaCli is a bit clunky to say the least.

Comment: Agreed megacli is clunky.  I wasn't aware of OpenManage, this is the only Dell server I have to deal with.  I would rather solve this with the tools already on the server, but if OpenManage is capable of fixing this and megacli is not, then I am open to it.

Answer (score 1):

You can set hotspare state to disk by command:
MegaCli -PDHSP -set -PhysDrv[32:1] -a0

Hot spare must be moved to rebuild state automatically.
Or you can try to use this option:
MegaCli -PdReplaceMissing -physdrv 32:1 -a0